# UserControl inside ContentControl with nested width/height

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-store-apps

I'm developing Windows Store App with using Caliburn Micro.

In one of the pages I have `ContentControl`, which display `UserControl`. In `UserControl` I have `GridView`.
 
 My question is: How to set `UserControl.Width` same as `ContentControl.Width`? 
Note: whet set `UserControl.Width=Auto` - width the same as `GridView.Width`

in page.xaml

```
<ContentControl x:Name="ActiveItem" />
```

in usercontrol.xaml

```
<UserControl
x:Class="Test.Views.GroupView"
xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
mc:Ignorable="d" Width="Auto" Height="Auto">

    <Grid Margin="0,20">
        <GridView x:Name="Groups" Margin="0" />
    </Grid>
</UserControl>
```

---

**UPDATE**

Adding

```
  VerticalAlignment="Stretch"
  HorizontalAlignment="Stretch"
```

To `UserControl` doesn't solve the problem.

Comment: Set UserControl's VerticalAlignment="Stretch" and HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" and it will fill whole your ContentControl.

Comment: @ViktorLaCroix, thanks for help, but I already try it, and it doesn't helped. Did you have another idea?

Comment: but it should :) Try to get rid of Width and Height and set ContentControl's background to some pretty color so you can see. from [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.frameworkelement.verticalalignment.aspx) `When Height and Width properties are explicitly set on an element, these measurements take layout precedent and cancel the regular effects of setting this property to Stretch.`

Comment: I tested it by setting color and reading size values. I know, that it must work (because it work for ex. on WPF or WP7), but it doesn't work(((

Comment: OK... that sucks... you can try other way around. Set your ContentControl's HorizontalContentAlignment="Stretch" and VerticalContentAlignment="Stretch" if this doesn't work nothing does :)

Comment: In my case the problem in this: ContentControl width/height correct (for ex. 1366/768), but UserControl width/height the same as UserControl child (Grid).

Comment: It will work only i if bind ActualSize of ContentControl to UserControl, but I think it's not the best way.

Comment: Hello @jimpanzer. Do you solved this issue? If so, could you please post answer. I have the same problem.

Comment: @AlexeiMalashkevich I post answer with solution. Hope it's helps you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Especially for @AlexeiMalashkevich
I solve it with using binding like this:

In root Page you have:

```
 <ContentControl x:Name="ActiveItem"/>
```

Then add the child page:

```
<Page
    Height="{Binding ActualHeight, ElementName=ActiveItem}"
    Width="{Binding ActualWidth, ElementName=ActiveItem}"
    ......
/>
```

And that's all.

Answer (score 13):

Figured this out after a lot of trial and error:

```
<ContentControl Name="MyContent" HorizontalContentAlignment="Stretch" VerticalContentAlignment="Stretch">
```

The key is to use the Horizontal/Vertical**Content**Alignment property (not the Horizontal/VerticalAlignment properties).

Comment: wow champ.. i have been stuck into this for hours.. thanks for the simple trick... :)

Answer (score 2):

Here is what you should do when problem like your's appears.

1. Try to set `ContentControl`'s `Background` property to some disturbing color. For example Purple or Pink. And also set `Background` property on your `UserControl` for example Green. It will allow you to see where exactly is your `ContentControl` and where is `UserControl`. If you can't see any Green you can tell that content of `UserControl` is stretched to fill whole `UserControl`.
2. Try to set `UserControl`'s `VerticalAlignment` and `HorizontalAlignment` properties to `Stretch`. [FrameworkElement.HorizontalAlignment](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.frameworkelement.horizontalalignment(v=vs.95).aspx), [VerticalAlignment](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.frameworkelement.verticalalignment(v=vs.95).aspx)

   > Note: In order to let these work. You **can't** explicitly set **Width** and **Height** on your *UserControl*.
3. Try to set `ContentControl`'s `VerticalContentAlignment` and `HorizontalContentAlignment` to `Stretch`. [Control.HorizontalContentAlignment](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.control.horizontalcontentalignment.aspx), [VerticalContentAlignment](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.control.verticalcontentalignment.aspx) . These stretches the child element to fill the allocated layout space of the parent element.
4. If you still see some Purple or Pink then something's wrong again :) you can check `Margin/Padding` [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms751709.aspx)

If it's still messed up. Then I don't know how else can I help you. Last possible solution would be binding. And I am not sure if it works.

```xml
<UserControl
Width="{Binding RelativeSource=
        {RelativeSource FindAncestor,
        AncestorType={x:Type ContentControl}},
        Path=ActualWidth}"
Height="{Binding RelativeSource=
        {RelativeSource FindAncestor,
          AncestorType={x:Type ContentControl}},
          Path=ActualHeight}">
...
</UserControl>
```

I hope something helps. I believe you that it could be really annoying problem.

Comment: A already tried all of that, except 4. Do you test it on win8/rt or just found it for wpf? I think it will be error with AncestorType.

Comment: Sorry I did not. I am not familiar with WinRT. Only xaml. But I failed to find the reason why it shouldn't work with WinRT.

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to bind UserControl's width to the ContentControl's ActualWidth.

```
<local:MyUserControl1 Height="50" Width="{Binding ElementName=contentControl, Path=ActualWidth}"/>
```

Here is some sample code:

```
<Page
    x:Class="stofUserControlWidth.MainPage"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:local="using:stofUserControlWidth"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    mc:Ignorable="d">

    <Grid Background="{StaticResource ApplicationPageBackgroundThemeBrush}">
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="2*"/>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <Border Background="Cyan"/>
        <ContentControl Grid.Column="1" x:Name="contentControl">
            <local:MyUserControl1 Height="50" Width="{Binding ElementName=contentControl, Path=ActualWidth}"/>
        </ContentControl>
    </Grid>
</Page>
```

Here is MyUserControl1.xaml code:

```
<UserControl
    x:Class="stofUserControlWidth.MyUserControl1"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:local="using:stofUserControlWidth"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    mc:Ignorable="d"
    d:DesignHeight="300"
    d:DesignWidth="400">

    <Grid Background="Magenta">        
    </Grid>
</UserControl>
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: I know it, but problem is: I dynamicly put user control to conetent control. And in xaml I have ContentControl like this <ContentControl Grid.Column="1" x:Name="contentControl"></ContentControl>

Comment: I see. Do you create the usercontrol in the code behind? If that's the case, creating binding in the code behind might help. What do you think?

Comment: I use Caliburn Micro for WinRT, and in ViewModel bind my controll to ContentControll.

Comment: I might misunderstand the question. But will setting HorizontalContentAlignment="Stretch" work for your case?

<ContentControl Grid.Column="1" x:Name="contentControl" HorizontalContentAlignment="Stretch">

Answer (score 1):

For me this is working:

```
<UserControl
                 ...
                    Height="{Binding ActualHeight,
                    RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type ContentControl}}}">

...

</UserControl>
```

You have to make sure that your `ContentControl` has the desired size.

For example my `ContentControl` look like this: It is always fill the whole size of the window. And the size of the `UserControl` in the `ContentControl` dinamically changes as well.

```
<Grid>
    <ContentControl HorizontalContentAlignment="Stretch" VerticalContentAlignment="Stretch" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" DataContext="{Binding StartViewModel}" Name="ContentArea" />
</Grid>
```