# Fill width on Windows Phone 8.1

Tags: xaml, windows-runtime, windows-phone-8.1, windows-phone

I'm developing an application using the Windows Phone 8.1 SDK, I write UI descriptions using `XAML` markup.

**I can't get a text box to fill width.**

I see similar questions already posted but they involve ListView.

I'm really confused. There seems to be no proportional sizing options. 
Tutorials show the use of explicit pixel counts in design.

> Is that really the preferred method on Windows? How am I supposed to
>   deal with unpredictable screen sizes in Windows?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The items which I had, which were failing to fill their parent, were inside a `ContentControl`. The `ContentControl` correctly filled its width, but its child, which was a `Grid`, would not.

I found the solution here – https://stackoverflow.com/a/17627257/5476004 – and I will echo that solution here in case this post is found by someone else searching about the same problem.

The `ContentControl` requires two special properties in order for its child element to fill the parent. They are `HorizontalContentAlignment` and `VerticalContentAlignment`. Like so":

```
<ContentControl Name="MyContent" HorizontalContentAlignment="Stretch" VerticalContentAlignment="Stretch">
…
</ContentControl>
```

Fill now occurs correctly.